# How do I proxy API requests in a JAMstack solution?

Tags: proxy, static-site, netlify, cross-site, jamstack

I'm developing a site that's virtually entirely static. I use a generator to create all the HTML.

However, my site is a front-end to a store embedded in its pages. I have a little node.js server proxying requests on behalf of the browser to the back-end store. All it does is provide the number of items in the shopping cart so I can keep the number updated on all pages of my site. That's because the browser doesn't allow cross-domain scripting. My server has to act as a proxy between the client and the store.

(The embedded store is loaded from the store's web site and so itself does not require proxying.)

I was hoping to eventually deploy to Netlify or some similar JAMstack provider. But I don't see how I'd proxy on Netlify.

What is the standard solution to this problem? Or is proxying unavailable to JAMstack solutions? Are there JAMstack providers that solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netlify does allow for proxy rewrites using redirect paths with status code 200.

You can store your [proxy redirects](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#rewrites-and-proxying) in `_redirects` at the root of your deployed site. In other words the file needs to exist at the root of the site directory to be deployed after a build.

`_redirects`

`/api/*  https://api.example.com/:splat  200`

So a call to:

```
/api/v1/gifs/random?tag=cat&api_key=your_api_key
```

will be proxied to:

```
https://api.example.com/v1/gifs/random?tag=cat&api_key=your_api_key
```

> If the API supports standard HTTP caching mechanisms like Etags or Last-Modified headers, the responses will even get cached by CDN nodes.

***NOTE:*** you can also [setup your redirects](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/) in your `netlify.toml`

Comment: Oh wow. That is awesome! I don't even need to write a proxy server. Thank you!